# Erro ao tentar instalar o PHP 7.2 no Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu

Já fazem quase dois dias que estou tentando instalar o PHP, mas
não consigo.

Eu baixei o pacote `tar.xz` do site oficial do PHP.

Executo o `tar xJf` para descompactar, porém quando chega no `./configure` aparecem os seguintes erros:

[image: Erros ao instalar o php7]

Já pesquisei tanto no google como aqui Stackoverflow mas não consegui achar nenhuma solução pra esse problema.

Comment: E pq vc nao instala com  o apt-get?

Comment: Extraia o arquivo em uma pasta que não contenha espaços e depois tente novamente.

Comment: Isso entra como programação ?

Comment: @RBZ Essa pergunta, na minha opinião, pode permanecer pois ela é relacionada à ["ferramentas comuns entre programadores"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Como [Valdeir](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/282662/erro-ao-tentar-instalar-o-php-7-2-no-ubuntu/282666#comment576988_282666) lembrou bem, caso seu ubuntu for 17.10 ou inferior seguir esses passos:**

> Certificar de ter o seguinte pacote instalado para que você possa adicionar repositórios:

```
apt install python-software-properties
```

> Adiciona o repositório Ondřej

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

> Aquele update maroto

```
apt update
```

**Instalação do php 7.2:**

> Instalação do apache e Zip

```
apt install -y apache2 zip
```

> Instalação do PHP e algumas extensões

```
apt-get install -y php7.2-mysql php7.2-curl php7.2-json php7.2-cgi php7.2 php7.2-mbstring libapache2-mod-php7.2 php7.2-ldap php-xdebug wget
```

> Criação do arquivo info.php

```
echo "<?php phpinfo() ?>" > /var/www/html/info.php
```

Lembrando: `service apache2 start // inicia o serviço do apache`

Comment: Se o Ubuntu dele for 17.10 ou inferior, não tem suporte ao PHP7.2, somente ao PHP7.1 ou inferior. Para instalar o PHP7.2, ele teria que adicionar um repositório, por exemplo, `ondrej/php` antes de fazer dessa forma.

Comment: Obrigado Valdier, tinha me esquecido deste detalhe, resposta atualizada.

Answer (score 2):

Porque não usa o xampp, muito prático e vem com tudo que vc precisa.

https://www.apachefriends.org/pt_br/download.html